# Google OAuth Login not working in IE

Tags: oauth-2.0

my website uses OAUTH2.0 to allow users to login with their gmail accounts. I use the following code to show the OAUTH login page:

Unfortunately this code throws an exception on IE (works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox).

Can anyone tell me whats the problem in IE. popup window is not closing and functionality not working in IE?

Comment: The code that i am using is var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
 var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
     if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
         window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
         var url = win.document.URL;
         acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
         tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
         expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
         win.close();
         validateToken(acToken);
     }
 }, 500);

Comment: On stackoverflow, you can edit your question to include your code in nice looking [code tags](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Nice looking questions are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with poltimer 5000 instead of 500 m.s.